# Internal storage shows is mounted twice on a Pixel 4a

Tags: root-access, storage

I have a rooted Pixel 4a on LineageOS 18. For some reason, whenever I plug my phone into my PC for file transfers I am seeing two internal storage drives being mounted. The Pixel 4a doesn't support SD cards, it's all internal storage. How do I make it show just 1 internal storage drive?

[image: Storage mounted twice]

Comment: Check the device manager if the device is there also seen twice. Change the device manager view to "Devices by connection" to see related USB devices together.